# Two jquery scripts conflict

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm having truble adding a lightbox script to my site, it's because i'm using the code from this tutorial http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/apple-style-splash-screen-jquery/ at the start of my site, so it loads an animation upon entering the site, however `

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Calling our splashScreen plugin and
    // passing an array with images to be shown

    $('#promoIMG').splashScreen({
        textLayers : [
            'img/thinner.png',
            'img/more_elegant.png',
            'img/our_new.png'
        ]
    });
});
```

The above code cancels out anything i use from the lightbox script found here: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/#

How do I get the two to work together?

I'm adding them to my header as follows (it's within wordpress):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/Javascript/jquery.splashscreen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/Javascript/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/Javascript/lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/Javascript/lightbox/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('#sidebar-menu a').lightBox();
    });
    </script>
```

Any suggestions will do!

Answer (score 3):

you should add a callback to the splash screen plugin to initialize lightbox once it's finished.

the callback should be executed on the click event which closes the spash

```
 splashScreen.click(function(){
    console.log('click event');
    splashScreen.fadeOut('slow', function(){
        console.log('callback 1');
        if(settings.finished != null) settings.finished();
    });    
});
```

then pass the callback when creating the object

```
$('#promoIMG').splashScreen({
    textLayers : [
        'img/thinner.png',
        'img/more_elegant.png',
        'img/our_new.png'
    ],
    finished: function(){
         console.log('callback 2');
         $('#sidebar-menu a').lightBox();                 
    }
});
```

**EDIT** add the `condole.log`'s to see what code actually gets reached.

Comment: Nothing happend, i added the first code to my splash.js file between lines 34 - 38 but still nothing and added the bottom part to my script.js file? am i missing something?

Comment: I've tried running your code above but i'm not good with js/jquery nor know how to check it for errors.

Comment: in chrome or safari: ctrl + shift + j then all `console.log` should show up in the console tab.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments, I was able to solve my problem by replacing $(document).ready(function() with jQuery(document).ready(function() and conflict issue solved.